# Add a grouping level to an existing Pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a frame with a dozen columns, `col1` through `col12`. This frame is large, so I want to minimize time spent in grouping.

So, I'd like to first group by 3 columns then by a 4th column. I'm using the aggregated data set and using the group as an entire object. So,

```
dfNew1 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"], as_index= False)
dfNew2 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], as_index= False)
```

This is expensive and IRL takes almost 10 minutes. What I'd like to do is retain some of my "work" for the second groupby. In an ideal world, something like

```
baseGrouper = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"])
dfNew1 = baseGrouper.reset_index()
dfNew2 = baseGrouper.groupby(["col4"]).reset_index() # DataFrameGroupBy does not actually have a "groupby" method
```

Surely there's some way to keep my grouping work and not doing it twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only care about having the groups, you can use [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) of the first group:

```
%%timeit
g1 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"], as_index= False)
g2 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], as_index= False)
g1['col12'].sum(), g2['col12'].sum() # needed for faithful timing comparison
# 378 ms ± 57.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
g1 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3"], as_index= False)
g2 = df.groupby([g1.ngroup(), "col4"], as_index= False)
g1['col12'].sum(), g2['col12'].sum()
# 264 ms ± 58.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The effect is greater with more columns:

```
%%timeit
g1 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"], as_index= False)
g2 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8"], as_index= False)
g1['col12'].sum(), g2['col12'].sum()
# 3.93 s ± 843 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
g1 = df.groupby(["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7"], as_index= False)
g2 = df.groupby([g1.ngroup(), "col8"], as_index= False)
g1['col12'].sum(), g2['col12'].sum()
# 1.68 s ± 544 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

*NB. depending on your real aggregation, there might be some filtering to perform.*

Used input (1M rows):

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(1_000_000, 12)),
                  columns=[f'col{x+1}' for x in range(12)])
```

Comment: Oh interesting. This almost works, but you lose the grouping columns on the second one?

Comment: Yes, that what I tried to say in my answer. You can however always `join` the missing columns afterwards (the exact method depends on what you do with the groups).